# Source media file referred to in manifest data doesn't exist:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sitecore, headless

I want to render images through Sitecore JSS and trying to include the JSON using the CommonFieldTypes.Image property. I'm following the documentation from https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/working-disconnected/manifest-api#fieldtypes but couldn't get it to work. I'm using Sitecore with Reactjs.

I'm passing the image as:

```
fields:{
 "articleImage": {
     "value": {
        "src": "../../../media/image.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
      }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about relative path and also it's not working for me with relative path, so change it to this :

```
fields:{
 "articleImage": {
     "value": {
        "src": "/data/media/image.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
      }
  },
}
```

it works for me maybe works for you.